# Toast Messages do not show up

Tags: java, android, toast

Hey I have a problem with toast messages which does not show up. I'm creating an app which displays user‘s message into Morse code and I want toast message show up to inform which character is diplayed now. But when I put it like below, toast messages do not show up. It's probably because next function which is called are somehow killing the previous one, cause when I removed other commands and left only `showStatus()` the messages appeared.
How can I deal with this situation?

```
public void dispDot()
    {
        final Parameters pM = cameraMorse.getParameters();
        pM.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        cameraMorse.setParameters(pM);
        MorseActivity.backgroundMorse.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background1on);
        waitFor(1);
        pM.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        cameraMorse.setParameters(pM);
        MorseActivity.backgroundMorse.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background1a);
    }
    //function that displays the line in Morse code
    public void dispLine()
    {
        final Parameters pM = cameraMorse.getParameters();
        pM.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        cameraMorse.setParameters(pM);
        MorseActivity.backgroundMorse.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background1on);
        waitFor(3);
        pM.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        cameraMorse.setParameters(pM);
        MorseActivity.backgroundMorse.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background1a);
    }

    public void showStatus(char character)
    {   
        //status1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        //status1.setText("Status: Now displaying "+character);
        toast = Toast.makeText(MorseActivity.this, "Displaying "+character,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 30);
        toast.show();
    }

    public void morseMessageTranslator()
    {
        morseMessage = textBox.getText().toString();
        morseMessage = morseMessage.toUpperCase();
        if(morseMessage.length()>0)
        {
            char character;
            for(int a=0;a<morseMessage.length();a++)
            {
                character=morseMessage.charAt(a);
                switch (character)
                {
                case 'A': //.-
                    showStatus('A');
                    dispDot();waitFor(1);dispLine();waitFor(1);
                    break;
                case 'B': //-...
                    showStatus('B');
                    dispLine();waitFor(1);dispDot();waitFor(1);dispDot();waitFor(1);dispDot();waitFor(1);
                    break;
```

UPDATE:
Ok it turns out that waitFor() function is the cause.

```
public void waitFor (final int time)
    {
        Thread waitthread = new Thread(new Runnable() { 
            // After call for background.start this run method call
            public void run() {


                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(time*500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
    waitthread.start();
    try {
        waitthread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

But still don't know how to show toast before the wait is launched.

Comment: Can you remove the `setGravity` method and try again?

Comment: recommend you make this data driven, the dot/line pattern should be defined in a data structure and your code to show the pattern no longer needs a giant switch statement.

Comment: I don't think Toast messages are destroyed the way you are thinking. Once shown they will show even if the activity is destroyed unless you explicitly cancel the Toast.

Comment: First check would be to see if your code is reaching the switch case you're expecting it to. Second, I would suggest you use something in the display to show the letter (like a TextView) rather than a toast as toast messages aren't context dependant and I would assume you only want to show a letter while the user is viewing the dots and dashes. If you move away from the toast, your issue becomes moot.

Comment: @boxed_I removing setGravity didn't help. No changes.

Comment: @Rohan Kandwal after rethinking it I think you're right but if so what is the source of the problem?

Comment: @Ben Pearson I've tried the TextBox but the issue is simmilar. The text in the text box is showing only for the last character in sentence and after it ends displaying the dots and lines. I implemented it like this status1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
status1.setText("Status: Now displaying "+character);

Comment: From where you are calling showStatus() ?

Comment: @ Rohan Kandwal From the inside of switch structure you can see it on the end of the source code listed in the first post.

Comment: Do any of the Toasts show up? I'm concerned since you have this in a for loop, so you might be experiencing this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15054732/toast-in-loop-is-not-displaying-properly

Comment: @anddev84 It shows up only for cases in which I call only showStatus() metohod and nothing more (no dispDot etc). For expample if user types character which is not supported by the morse code eg."$" switch goes to default statement and there is only showStatus(character) function and the Toast Message works fine for this case.

Comment: @creatice1933 try using the `Toast.makeText(MorseActivity.this, "Displaying "+character,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` instead of your toast.

Comment: @Rohan Kandwal I've tried no changes

Answer (score 2):

As your comments on this question show, the reason your Toasts aren't showing is because of your `waitFor()` method. As described, this performs a pointless calculation, which a) wastes precious CPU time (and therefore battery) and b) performs this on the UI thread. This means that anything that should happen on the UI thread won't happen all the time `waitFor()` is running, including Toasts.

You'll have to include some sort of threading here to get over this issue (the Android Developers website has a [good tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/index.html)). You'll want the dispDot, dispLine and waitFor calls to happen on a background thread. Bear in mind that if any of these three methods interact with your UI, they must do that back on the UI thread (see Communicating with the UI thread in the linked tutorial).

***Previous (wrong) answer***

You're creating your `Toast`s, but not calling `show()` on them! It's a very easy mistake to make. Just change the line:

```
toast = Toast.makeText(MorseActivity.this, "Displaying "+character,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
```

to

```
toast = Toast.makeText(MorseActivity.this, "Displaying "+character,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help. Still the same issue

Comment: Indeed, I've noticed my answer is completely wrong. What does your `waitFor()` method do? If you're blocking the main thread with it (using `Thread.sleep()`) then that will almost certainly kill the toasts

Comment: waitFor() is just a for loop which does some pointless calculation to waist time :) I know that this is very primitive solution but it works for me and I'm stil a beginner:) public void waitFor (int seconds)
 {
  for(int wait=0;wait<seconds*20000000;wait++)
  {
   int nothing=(1000000*99)/33;
  }
 
 }

Comment: see the updated answer - it doesn't explain everything but should give you a good start.

Comment: I've read your update and as I've said earlier I know that this waitFor() is primitive and GPU waisting but still I don't understand why you're saying that it's killing toast messages?

Comment: It is _CPU_ wasting. That means that on the UI thread (where views - including toasts) are drawn, nothing else can happen whilst waitFor() is running. Therefore, the toasts can't be drawn because your calculation is using the CPU

Comment: OK that explains a lot. So I'll try to figure out how to solve it with multithreads usage

Comment: Best of luck! If you have any questions, comment and we can talk on chat at some point

Comment: I tried few things and first of all I've changed the waitFor function but I guess I've swaped one problem to another :D Now I'm sleeping the UIThread public void waitFor (int seconds)
 {
  try {
   Thread.sleep(seconds*1000);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 } It's working but again the toast messages are kille due to UItread sleep so this wasn't the best idea I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Add .show() to the end of you toast codes

```
toast = Toast.makeText(MorseActivity.this, "Displaying "+character,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```