# LocationManager minTime won't work properly

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager

I want to get user's location every 5 minutes, so I created a `Service` with the following codes:

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class Tracker extends Service {

    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private long minTime = 300000; // miliseconds
    private float minDistance = 10; // meters
    private boolean gpsStatus;
    private boolean networkStatus;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.i("Location2", "Location: Created");
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i("Location2", "Location: Started");

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        gpsStatus = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        networkStatus = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(getProviderName(), minTime, minDistance, locationListener);

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    private void resetLocationProvider() {
        Log.e("Location2", "Provider Reset");
        deleteLocationListener();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(getProviderName(), minTime, minDistance, locationListener);
    }

    private void deleteLocationListener() {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
    }

    private LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            resetLocationProvider();
            Log.e("Location2", "Provider Enabled: " + provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            resetLocationProvider();
            Log.e("Location2", "Provider Disabled: " + provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.i("Location2", "Location Time: " + TimeToDate.getDate(location.getTime(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
            Log.i("Location2", "Location Provider: " + location.getProvider());
            Log.i("Location2", "Location Accuracy: " + location.getAccuracy());
            Log.i("Location2", "Location Latitude: " + location.getLatitude());
            Log.i("Location2", "Location Longitude: " + location.getLongitude());

            if (gpsStatus != locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                gpsStatus = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                resetLocationProvider();
                return;
            }

            if (networkStatus != locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
                networkStatus = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                resetLocationProvider();
            }
        }
    };

    private String getProviderName() {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_MEDIUM); // Chose your desired power consumption level.
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE); // Choose your accuracy requirement.
        criteria.setSpeedRequired(false); // Chose if speed for first location fix is required.
        criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false); // Choose if you use altitude.
        criteria.setBearingRequired(false); // Choose if you use bearing.
        criteria.setCostAllowed(false); // Choose if this provider can waste money :-)

        // Provide your criteria and flag enabledOnly that tells
        // LocationManager only to return active providers.
        return locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        deleteLocationListener();
        super.onDestroy();
    };

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

As is seen, I've used a `minTime` of `300,000 ms`, But I got a location every about 20 seconds rather than every 5 minutes. As [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.location.LocationListener,%20android.os.Looper)) says:

> The elapsed time between location updates will never be less than
>   minTime, although it can be more depending on the Location Provider
>   implementation and the update interval requested by other applications

And also I know, an `active provider` is not a good choice for a `background process`. However, what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Check gps time difference between previous lat lng to current lnt lng

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13093796/1922137), I changed my codes to:

```
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if (location != null) {
                if (location.getProvider().equals(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) && android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
                    Log.i("TEST", "DATE: " + TimeToDate.getDate(location.getTime(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
                    Log.i("TEST", "LAT: " + location.getLatitude());
                    Log.i("TEST", "LONG: " + location.getLongitude());
                    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(getProviderName(), minTime, minDistance, locationListener);
                        }
                    }, minTime);
                }
                ...
```

And now it works.